# How to filter blueprint urls from url rules?

Tags: flask

I want to make Website Menu and allow administrator to choose from known url in flask-admin for this I have main blueprint and it has some endpoints, I want to make function which will return known endpoints for Menu model for administrator to choose right url and pack it with data.

I have tried for loop for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():

```
@app.route("/site-map")
def site_map():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        # Filter out rules we can't navigate to in a browser
        # and rules that require parameters

        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
        links.append(rule.endpoint)

    return render_template("all_links.html", links=links)
```

But the code above is giving me all routes also for flask-admin

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an additional test to filter out endpoints for `admin.`:

```
if "GET" in rule.methods \
  and has_no_empty_params(rule) \
  and not rule.endpoint.startswith("admin."):
    # Add link to list of links
```

Comment: thanks but I was searching the way when I will iterate in rules by blueprint names